# How to send HttpRequest(string) and then Receive answer in C#

Tags: c#, http-post, httpresponse, http-request

I need to implement an application to post string like HttpRequest to specify IP address and then receive answer in httpRespons form.
Here is code for sending

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.10");
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = "string I want to post";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
```

I'm not able to test this code. Is this code OK?

Here is code for receive answer:

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
richTextBox1.AppendText(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
richTextBox1.AppendText(responseFromServer);
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Is this code OK?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is should be asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your failing to dispose multiple disposable objects

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct,but i think `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);` should append Encoding :`StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream,encoding);`